# How big would my telescope have to be if I wanted to see the Mars rover from my backyard?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, astronomy, estimation, telescopes

I imagine that with a big enough telescope, I would be able to zoom in and see the Mars rover in enough detail to make out the details (like the wheels, cameras, etc.). How large would the telescope have to be? (or how can I calculate this value?)

Comment: Link: [Why not use Hubble to look at the lunar landers?](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/badastronomy/2008/08/12/moon-hoax-why-not-use-telescopes-to-look-at-the-landers/) Answer: Hubble's resolution for objects on the Moon is about 200 meters.

Comment: @JEB if it's not on Mars is it still a Mars rover?

Comment: Just as a practical matter, the resolution is probably (certainly, in the absense of adaptive optics) going to be limited by atmospheric distortion, more than by the size of the telescope.  That's part of the reason Hubble gives better images than Earthbound telescopes, even though they're much larger.

Comment: @jamesqf - You've hit on the key. The telescope needs to be big enough to extend beyond the majority of the atmosphere. Also, We'll want it to hold a vacuum. :)

Comment: Now I want to see Randall Munroe answer this in an [xkcd What If?](https://what-if.xkcd.com/)

Comment: I assume we're talking about a frictionless spherical telescope in a vacuum?

Comment: Isn't this a question for astronomy.SE or space.SE?

Comment: @dalearn This is about optics in a hypothetical situation so this definitely looks like a physics question more than an astronomy or space question.

Comment: Great YouTube video on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jq-NnQmI_2c

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Telescope resolution is all about apparent angles. From the sounds of it, the lowest resolution you'd settle for would be something capable of resolving about $1 \operatorname{cm}$ objects, right? Well, the distance between the Earth and Mars varies, depending on the time of year, from around $0.5\operatorname{AU}$ to $2.5\operatorname{AU}$ ($7.5\times 10^{10} \operatorname{m}$ to $3.7\times 10^{11} \operatorname{m}$). At those distances, a $1$ centimeter object subtends an [angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(geometry)) of
$$\theta = \frac{s}{d},$$
which is $1.5\times 10^{-13}\operatorname{rad}$ to $2.7\times 10^{-14}\operatorname{rad}$.

The [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution) of a circular telescope is given by the formula
$$\theta = \frac{1.22\lambda}{D}.$$
So, assuming you're using visible light, with $\lambda \approx 500\operatorname{nm}$, to resolve those $1$ centimeter objects it would require telescopes with a diameter of $D=4.6\times 10^6\operatorname{m}$ to $7.4\times 10^7\operatorname{m}$. For reference, the diameter of Earth is about $1.3\times 10^7\operatorname{m}$.

Note that the sheer size is only one of the challenges. In order to achieve this theoretical resolution you would need the surface of the mirror to have the correct shape everywhere to within about a wavelength of light. In other words, this Earth-sized mirror could not have any imperfections larger than about $500\operatorname{nm}$. To see some of the information related to getting ordinary lenses and mirrors correct to this level see the [Wikipedia article on optically flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flat).

Comment: Check your answer by also solving for MRO from Mars orbit: https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/MRO/news/mro-20061204.html

Comment: One could add that you don't need a full-sized mirror for that.  You only need to capture parts of the wave over such a distance.  So in principle, if you had two normal-sized telescopes on opposite sides of the earth, both looking at Mars, and you could do an interference of their captured light, you might also reach that resolution.  Then, the problem will probably be the low light intensity (the amount of photons per second coming from the rover and reaching the pair of telescopes will be minuscule).  But it would in principle be doable, without making a mirror, the size of the earth.

Comment: @entrop-x With two mirrors separated like that you'd only have that resolution in that one direction. To make an image you'd need to be able to get that resolution in multiple directions, so you'd need more than two mirrors, or movable mirrors. Add in the problem of actually coherently interfering the signals, and it's probably intractable. We can only do that sort of thing in radio because of the abundance of photons, and the inter-photon coherence - both are lacking in the optical.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake you don't need inter-photon coherence of the signal; if the Mars Rover had a laser which we could use for calibration of a multi-mirror system to capture a wavefront in one scoop, that would be enough. But indeed two mirrors would help little with image resolution (that's only sufficient for localisation of point sources); rather you'd need a whole ensemble or mirrors, all aligned with submicrometre precision... not going to happen soon.

Comment: What would be truly ironic is if the focal point for such a mirror is farther from the Earth than $0.5$ AU.

Comment: @All this, of course, assumes no atmospheric interference.  Even for the largest telescopes today, their resolution is limited relative to the theoretical best resolution because of unstable air messing up images from space (though there is technology used to correct for this).  A humongous telescope still embedded in Earth's atmosphere will still have very limited resolution.

Comment: @Joshua Given the size described, embedding in Earth's atmosphere is less of a problem than that the rover is embedded in Mars's.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake, that is also true.

Comment: How can the maximum distance between Earth and Mars only be 1.5 AU? Alone on the Earth orbit, 2 "opposite" points should be around 2 AU apart (1 AU to middle/sun, 1 AU from middle to opposite point), so the maximum distance between Earth and Mars should be further than that....

Comment: @hoffmale Good point. Fixing calculation.

Answer (score 19):

***Short answer***

## REALLY BIG

***Long answer***

There are several parameters that need to be controlled in order to make a properly-functioning telescope, but arguably the two most important parameters are its *magnification power* and its *aperture size*.

Magnification is defined fairly straightforward as the ratio between how big the object looks when looking at it through the eyepiece of the telescope to how big the object looks when looking at it with the naked eye. This depends on the properties of the lenses you use in your telescope. For a fairly simple telescope, you will have two lenses: the *objective lens* at the front of the telescope, and the *eyepiece lens*, the lens you actually put your eye up to in order to look at the night sky. The magnification can be expressed in terms of each lens' *focal length*,

$$M = \frac{f_o}{f_e}$$

where $f_o$ is the focal length of the objective lens, and $f_e$ is the focal length of the eyepiece lens. The sum of the two focal lengths will give you a rough estimate on how long the body of the telescope needs to be. [This webpage](http://www.rocketmime.com/astronomy/Telescope/Magnification.html) gives a bit more detail on the derivation of this equation and the intuition behind the physics of refraction in lenses.

Once you have the correct lenses for the magnification you desire, the next parameter you need to take into account is the size of the telescope's *aperture* -- the opening of the telescope that actually captures the light coming from the object you want to look at. If you want to see a brighter, more resolved image, you're going to want a bigger aperture. The equation determining the field of view you can resolve is given on this page in Sean E. Lake's answer. The $D$ in his equation will give you the size of the aperture you need for your telescope.

Answer (score 12):

The above answers have excellent math, but they neglect the most important factor: your hypothetical telescope is in your backyard, on the surface of planet Earth.

No matter how big you make the mirrors or lenses, your telescope cannot see the Mars rover from Earth, because of [atmospheric distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_seeing). You know how stars "twinkle"? You know how on a hot day, sometimes the ground shimmers? The air acts like a big blurry wobbly lens, which any ground-based telescope has to look through, limiting the level of detail that is physically possible to see.

When looking 50 million km away (such as Mars at closest approach), an ideal ground-based telescope might see objects that measure [many tens of kilometers across](http://www.1728.org/angsize.htm). Anything smaller would be blurred out. [Adaptive optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_optics) might manage to get the resolution into single-digit kilometers, but you're trying to see things 1000x smaller than that. It's not going to happen.

p.s. As @Pere suggests in the comments, you can circumvent this problem by placing the device off-Earth, then sending the image back via radio. Congratulations, [your telescope already exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Mars_Science_Laboratory#Self-portraits)!

Comment: If you look at the numbers the other answers produce, any telescope is going to be tall enough that it sticks out of the atmosphere.

Comment: So what he really needs is an Earth-sized space telescope, with a receiver in his backyard.

Comment: If the space telescope is wisely placed, it doesn't need to be that big. He example, he can place in it in orbit around Mars or, even better, sitting on Mars a couple of meters from the rover. Anyway, he would need a large receiving antenna that might not fit in his backyard.

Comment: @Barmar If you go that route, the more obvious solution would be a telescope in Mars orbit looking down,  transmitting the signal back to Earth. Building a capable antenna is in this case a lot easier than building a capable telescope.

Comment: Actually, twinkling or, more accurately, scintillation is not caused by atmospheric distortion/refraction. If it were a result of refraction there would be displacement, which does not occur, and there would not be changes in colour, which there is. Instead, it's the result of interference of the wavefront of plane wave light passing through turbulence. Planets don't scintillate because their light isn't planar relative to the pupil.

Comment: @Danikov Is [Sky & Telescope](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-resources/why-do-stars-twinkle/) wrong?

Comment: @Danikov, do you have a reference? That contradicts what I have read.

Comment: I have some evidence: https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap110428.html Ironically the caption cites the wrong effect, but the changes in colour is a particular nail in the refraction explanation. John W. Kuehne has also said a lot on this rather popular myth: https://sites.google.com/site/fresnel4twinkle/ It's not that refraction doesn't occur, it's just not the primary cause of scintillation